# How to allow single sign on between multiple cakephp 3 apps on the same server?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, redis, cakephp-3.0

**Situation**

I currently have two cakephp 3 apps on the same Ubuntu server using the same MySQL with different databases.

Let's call the first app `Hammy` (which uses the database name `hammy`)
Let's call the second app `Chewy` (which uses the database name `chewy`)

`Hammy` was first built for a particular customer's company so there are `users` and `groups` tables in the `hammy` database.

Subsequently, I needed to build `Chewy` for the same customer and another customer.

Inside `chewy`, I have designed `users` and `groups` tables but with an additional column called `account_id`.

These are the domains I use for the above setup:

customerA.hammy.com
customerA.chewy.com
customerB.chewy.com

**What I want**

What I want is that after a user in customerA.hammy.com clicks on a link that sends her to customerA.chewy.com, she can continue to access customerA.chewy.com

Regardless if the user logins at customerA.hammy.com or customerA.chewy.com, she can access both web apps without any issues.

A single-signon basically.

**My options**

These are my thoughts as to how I can solve this problem.

1. I can create a 3rd web app that is basically just a web service that basically handles authentication for both Hammy and Chewy.

I am familiar with building a webservice using CakePHP 3.x

However, I am not familiar with the authenticate options.

This is what I used in both Hammy and Chewy's `AppController`

```
$authOptions = [
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'overview'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login',
        ],
    ];
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', $authOptions);
```

2. use redis

The drawback is I have never tried Redis, so I do not even have a conceptual idea how to go about implementing this.

Any advice will be welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: what about using isAuthorized in the AppController, wich can return true conditionally

Comment: What if make session to work with database , and both applications will use same database with various prefix.

Comment: Or various databases , and one script working with script which will synchronize that two databases session tables ?

Comment: You could try implementing stateless authentication - http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-stateless-authentication-systems

Comment: @Kim Stacks : How did you implemented this? Any suggestion so that I could also do accordingly

Answer (score 1):

[CakePHP 3.x doc : Manually Logging Users In](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#manually-logging-users-in)

With this, you can avoid the "natural" cakephp login, and force it to log your user like you want.

The big problem will be that you don't have any shared part between you Cakephp sub-domaine.

For me (but that's perfectible) :

- I'll make a shared folder/DB on the server,
- generate a token on every login (natural or auto),
- stored it in the shared part and in a user cookie,

And on change Dom, check if the cookie exist, if yes, check if it's legit, if yes, generate a new token an erase the old one and log auto my user on the new Dom.

With this, you can keep data linked to the profile in the shared part (serialised array in a file or a DB field)...

Careful with the security risk to use a token as a password :

- one use only for a token,
- erase old token,
- try to read a bit about keeping token secure on client side

---

BTW, It may be a stupid idea, but if you run the same cakephp version on the same server, why not using symbolic link to make a shared folder for every cakephp session ?